# Display WhatsApp group chat on a public webpage

Tags: web, whatsapp

I am looking for a method to Display WhatsApp group chat on a public webpage.
The reason for that is hat I want to make some WhatsApp groups content searchable via Google.

Do we have any available solution for that ?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

one option to get what you need is adding a "listener" to the whatsapp group. It would essentially read all the messages on the group, and you could post them on a web page as you need.

On this example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCmoay0G86M all the messages are logged out on a node-red debug node.

I hope it helps.